# Testing cipher suite of Apache

Tags: security, apache-2.4

While I was searching related questions, I saw this: 
https://superuser.com/questions/109213/how-do-i-list-the-ssl-tls-cipher-suites-a-particular-website-offers

I tried working on the solutions provided but I haven't found my solution.

I have 2 server, the test and the production server.

Both of them host an application, test and prod.
This application requires a reverse proxy so I set up Apache for this.

I was asked to improve the cipher suite used for the HTTPS.

The **PROD** server uses, in apache, this:

```
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite DES-CBC-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!EXP
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
```

The **TEST** server, which I'm currently working on, was updated for using this:

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCompression      off
SSLSessionTickets   off
```

It is time to test if the new configuration works (well, it already should, but you know...).

From a **3rd TEST** machine I ran:

```
curl https://test.servertest.com/test1
against the TEST server
and
curl https://prodserver.com/accept
to the PROD one.
```

Reading the APACHE error log from both the **TEST** and **PROD** servers, I do not see differences.

```
TEST:
[Tue Oct 23 13:57:10.846249 2018] [ssl:trace3] [pid 13130] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1795): [remote 1.1.1.1:5555] OpenSSL: Handshake: done
[Tue Oct 23 13:57:10.846257 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 13130] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1844): [remote 1.1.1.1:5555] AH02041: Protocol: TLSv1, Cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA (256/256 bits)

PROD:
[Tue Oct 23 13:58:04.192403 2018] [ssl:trace3] [pid 6856] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1795): [remote 2.2.2.2:6666] OpenSSL: Handshake: done
[Tue Oct 23 13:58:04.192409 2018] [ssl:debug] [pid 6856] ssl_engine_kernel.c(1844): [remote 2.2.2.2:6666] AH02041: Protocol: TLSv1, Cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA (256/256 bits)
```

Probably CURL might not be the best way for testing the cipher suite (?) but my question is:
**How can I be sure that the changes I applied are correct** (beside finding the ciphers suite themselves in the Apache manual) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`curl -vv -k https://test.example.com` will output some of useful TLS info, but will only negotiate a *single* protocol and  cipher, rather than testing *every* possible and supported SSL/TLS version and cipher.

```
curl -vv https://test.example.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://test.example.com/
*   Trying 10.9.8.7...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to test.example.com (10.9.8.7) port 443 (#0)
...
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
```

A useful online testing tool is Qualis SSL labs https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ or run your own tests using the nice wrapper script from https://testssl.sh/  around the commandline `openssl` tool/library.

A few simple openssl commands to test for the correct SSLProtocol level are:

```
 openssl s_client -connect test.example.com.com:443 -ssl3
```

Which is supposed to return a failure when SSLv3 is disabled with `SSLProtocol -SSLv3`

> ```
> 140304709433232:error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:
>      sslv3 alert handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:1493:SSL alert number 40
> 140304709433232:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:ssl3_write_bytes:
>      ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:659:
> ```

and similar for testing TLS protocol 1.0

```
 openssl s_client -connect test.example.com:443 -tls1
```

we should again see a handshake failure:

> ```
>  routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert protocol version:s3_pkt.c:1493:SSL alert number 70
>  ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:659:
> ```

```
 openssl s_client -connect test.example.com:443 -tls1_1
```

> ```
> 139920359683984:error:1409442E:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:
> tlsv1 alert protocol version:s3_pkt.c:1493:SSL alert number 70
> ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:659:
> ```

When testing the allowed TLS protocol level 1.2

```
  openssl s_client -connect test.example.com:443 -tls1_2
```

one should see a successful connection and a the details of a TLS certificate:

> ```
> depth=2 O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
>  verify return:1
>  depth=1 C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
>  verify return:1
>  depth=0 CN = test.example.com
>  verify return:1
>  ---
>  Certificate chain
>  0 s:/CN=test.example.com
>    i:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
>  1 s:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
>    i:/O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3
> ---
> Server certificate
> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
> MIIGFTCCBP2gAwIBAgISBEs83Gyi/cFWkX3BtmTHk3R5MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUA
> ...
> ```

A useful cheat sheet for good TLS settings for a number of of different servers is: https://cipherli.st/

Comment: All good info, thanks! I was trying already the curl command. From the CURL of your example and the log on my server, the cipher suite match. Means that my tests were right. What I don't understand is why both of my servers accept these HIGH ciphers, which is correct, while I was told to upgrade them on the PROD server because are weak, saying that those that I use are `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256`. I can not see anywhere these last cipher suite used in my server(s). I just see the HIGH one.

Comment: Yes, checked (and done) everything that you said. It totally match with my settings. I am not sure now why I was told that my server uses those weak cipher suite while indeed it is not. I am confused. At least I know that all the tests that I have run are correct

Comment: I think I will accept your answer because I like how you wrote it. It's helpful. I am still confused because I do not know where this client of mine got that cipher suite list though.